# Displaying Viewmodel in View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So I have a view model class called Reports that looks like this:

```
    public class MemberReports
    {
        public Member Members { get; set; }
        public Event Events { get; set; }
        public MemberClubHours Memberclubhours { get; set; }
        public VolunteerEvents Volunteerevents { get; set; }
    }
```

It contains Members, which has a many to many relationship with events, MemberClubHours, and volunteer events. Basically I want to display all the data I have on a member in a view called reports. But I'm having difficulty accomplishing this, any advice?
here are all the classes:

```
    public class Member
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(4, ErrorMessage = "PIN must be 4 numbers long"), MinLength(4, ErrorMessage = "PIN must be 4 numbers long")]
        public string PIN { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name ="First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
        public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<VolunteerEvents> Vevents { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<MemberClubHours> Hours { get; } = new HashSet<MemberClubHours>();
    }
```

```
public class Event
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    public DateTime? EventDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Start Time")]
    public TimeSpan EventStartTime { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "End Time")]
    public TimeSpan EventEndTime { get; set; }
    public int EventTotalTime{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Member> Members { get; set; }


}
```

```
    public class MemberClubHours
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ClockIn { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ClockOut { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Member Member { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class VolunteerEvents
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display( Name ="Date")]
    public DateTime? VEventDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Start Time")]
    public TimeSpan VEventStartTime { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "End Time")]
    public TimeSpan VEventEndTime { get; set; }
    public int VEventTotalTime { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Member> Members { get; set; }
}
```

here is the controller, which is were I'm a little confused, should i iterate through the classes to get the information to be stored in the viewmodel?

```
         public ActionResult Reports()//reports page
        {
            var Data = new MemberReports()
            {


            };

            return View(Data);
        }
```

and lastly the view here:

```
@model IEnumerable<ClubChallenge.ViewModels.MemberReports>
@{

                ViewBag.Title = "Reports";
}

<table>

    @foreach (var data in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    }




</table>
```

Comment: Will you include Members, Events, MemberClubHours, VolunteerEvents classes and properties in your question? Also include your controller code on how you are creating the view model. Thanks.

Comment: okay, i added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like in all of these navigation properties, you assigned the `virtual` keyword. The `virtual` keyword in entity framework indicates that this related entity will be lazy-loaded or automatically loaded without having the need to query.

```
public class Member
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<VolunteerEvents> Vevents { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MemberClubHours> Hours { get; } = new HashSet<MemberClubHours>();
}
```

You might not need the MemberReports after all, since the navigation properties are automatically loaded, you could just search for a member and return it to the view. Try this;

```
public ActionResult Reports()
{
   // If your navigation properties doesn't have the virtual keyword, you need to write your query like this;
   // var member = context.Members.Include(m=>m.Events).Include(m=>m.Vevents).Include(m=>m.Hours).ToList();

   // but since, you put virtual, you could just do this;
   // all the other navigation properties are automatically loaded
   var members = context.Members.ToList();

   // you could immediately access them like this

   // get the first member
   Console.WriteLine(members.FirstOrDefault().Events.Count);
   Console.WriteLine(members.FirstOrDefault().Events.FirstOrDefault().Name);

   Console.WriteLine(members.FirstOrDefault().Vevents.Count);
   Console.WriteLine(members.FirstOrDefault().Vevents.FirstOrDefault().Name);

   Console.WriteLine(members.FirstOrDefault().Hours.Count);
   Console.WriteLine(members.FirstOrDefault().Hours.ClockIn.ToString());

   return View(member);
}
```

Then in your view, you can do a nested loop. First loop through member, then inside loop through the navigated properties;

```
@model IEnumerable<ClubChallenge.Members>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Reports";
}

<table>

    @foreach (var data in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
               @foreach(var event in data.Events){
                  <text>@event.Name ,</text>
               }
            </td>
            <td>
               @foreach(var vevent in data.Vevents){
                  <text>@vevent.Name ,</text>
               }
            </td>
            <td>
               @foreach(var hour in data.Hours){
                  <text>@hour.ClockIn.ToString() ,</text>
               }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```